# How to start blinking of my text label when a button pressed?

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to create a text label in tkinter which should start blinking when "1" button is pressed .
For that i tried with help of tkinter documentation and other tutorial on google,but eventually failed to create logic successfully as i am new to python,i found little hard to handle event object.
Here is my code.

```
import tkinter as Tk

flash_delay = 500  # msec between colour change
flash_colours = ('white', 'red') # Two colours to swap between

def flashColour(object, colour_index):
    object.config(background = flash_colours[colour_index])
    root.after(flash_delay, flashColour, object, 1 - colour_index)

root = Tk.Tk()
root.geometry("100x100")
root.label = Tk.Text(root, text="i can flash",
                   background = flash_colours[0])
root.label.pack()
#root.txt.insert(Tk.END,"hello")


root.button1=Tk.Button(root,text="1")
root.button1.pack()

root.button.place(x=10,y=40,command = lambda: flashColour(root.label, 0))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi Adee, welcome to the site. Please don't edit your question to ask something different after you've received help with your original issue. That makes the answers you've received no longer make sense. It's impossible to answer a moving target! If you have another question, you should ask it separately. There's no problem asking several related questions. You can even link back to the earlier questions from the later questions if it would help provide context (though you don't necessarily need to).

Comment: @Blckknght, Ok i understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`place` does not accept `command` as argument. You should pass it to `Button` widget with `lambda`.

```
root.button=Tk.Button(root,text="1",command = lambda: flashColour(root.label, 0))
root.button.pack()
#root.button.place(x=10,y=40)  # you should use either `pack` or `place` but not both
```